# Profile Page for Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, android-app

I would like to be able to view my profile from within the Android app.

**IDEAS:**

1. Link before/after the "Feed" link that will lead you to your Stack Exchange Profile.
2. Icon link to the right of the site links in the "Favorite Sites" list that leads to that site's profile.
3. Link in the notifications menu at the top that leads to Stack Exchange Profile.
4. Clicking asker/answerer user name should link to site profile.

Is there a specific reason that accessing profiles has been blocked on the app?

Comment: Yes please. I'm embarrassed by how important it is for check my reputation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, thank you for your time in testing our Android app - we appreciate it.

We do have a user profile view planned for our beta release which is now underway.  Most of the ideas you have here will be implemented.

Answer (score 6):

This is now live as of version 0.1.78 which came out on 12/12/2013.

You can tap on anyone's face anywhere in the app to see their profile and you also have an item in the left-side nav with your name on it which you can tap to view your own.

Viewing your profile contains a bit more information than when viewing another user's profile, and that's by design, check it out and let us know what you think!

[image: Sidebar link]

Comment: Excellent! Any chance we could have the app open links to user profiles? Or that usernames on comments could also take us to profiles?

Comment: @HodofHod both excellent ideas I'm sad I didn't think of, make a feature-request for them so we can both hopefully get more hats!

Comment: [HATTTSSSSS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211883/168660)

Comment: I opened my profile from the application, but they put everything in details, for example here from the site I can see how many questions I have asked and how many answers and my favorite posts and my votes,... as a summary somehow and in a very neat way, but can I do this from the application? I mean is there a way for me to choose what specific thing I want to view, instead of viewing all the details together?