# Should we suggest features we want added to the Android app?

Tags: discussion, android-app

The Android app is still in its alpha stages, and therefore not everything has been added yet. So, should we suggest things we want added to the Android app on Meta and Google+, or will they just be [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)?

Comment: I think you should suggest features that would make the current set of functionality more usable rather than something totally new. Example: improvements to the Q&A interface would be great but asking for tag pages will probably be status-deferred.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is completely OK to bring up feature requests for the Android app here on Meta.

I know that it was stated somewhere in the G+ group that such requests should be posted here with the tags [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app).

Some will be tagged as [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) such as this one of mine: [Profile Page for Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191301/profile-page-for-android-app)

I'm unsure of any other tags such requests will receive though.