# Ability to update profile from the Stack Exchange Android App

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, android-app

It would be nice to update the profile page from within the app.

Perhaps not many people update their profiles more frequently, but when required to do so, I would prefer to do it from the app instead of the mobile browser.

Comment: I'm waiting for the time when the Android App can do the exact same things as are possible on the website.

Comment: Maybe after this: [Profile Page for Android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191301)

Comment: @HodofHod nope. Two full years passed, and the chance that editing the profile will be added/supported is well below zero.

Comment: Review would be much nicer than a profile update for me

Comment: [The mobile apps are no longer supported.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028/335251) I'm guessing that's why the [status-declined] tag was added.