# Search on duplicates is broken

Tags: bug, search, duplicate-questions

I have seen quite some posts about the duplicate search being broken, and I had like to do another report which really hurts users trying to find duplicates.

I try to find a post using the exact title I have seen somewhere else (or very well known canonical questions). I type that question title exactly in the search box:

> [image: screen shot]

It can't find it, while [it is obviously there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201594/245360), literally. Instead it gives a bunch of unrelated posts.

Luckily Google knows where to find that post:

> [image: google]

So now I can copy the link and close the question.

Comment: At least, this [earned me a hat](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/search-you-must)...