# How to see a user's profile in the Stack Exchange Android application?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-exchange, android-app

In the Android application of Stack Exchange, I can't see my profile, nor other user's profiles. Is there any way to see any user's profile in the Android application?

Comment: Are you talking about the official android app (currently in beta)? Or some third party android app? Do you have an app store link?

Comment: I have signup for official android app testing.

Comment: Good to see it's planned - I thought I'd just failed to intuit how or fat-fingered the wrong target area.

Comment: This appears to be [completed now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191301/profile-page-for-android-app).