# Add more ways to open user profiles in the Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, android-app

The wonderful app devs [have just added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211865/168660) user profiles to the app. This means that we can now view the profile for any user by clicking on their avatar when attached to a question or an answer.

Unfortunately, the app does not open direct links to profiles, (i.e., [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/168660/hodofhod)), nor does tapping a comment's owner's username take you to the user's profile.

Perhaps these could be added?

<sup><sup><sup><sup>[HATTSSSS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191301/profile-page-for-android-app/211865?noredirect=1#comment681386_211865)</sup></sup></sup></sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great suggestions. They're both available in version 0.1.75 coming out later tonight.

Comment: P.S. [HATS!](https://twitter.com/jc4p/status/412628565641818112)

Comment: @ Kasra: [More HATS opportunities!!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid-app%5D+user%3A168660+-%5Bstatus-*%5D) ;)