# "My Profile" Page For Site App

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Android app has no view per site profile page.

I have both an iPhone and Android phone which I use both semi regularly.  I have noticed one specific feature per site "My Profile" pages doesn't exist on Android but does exist on iPhone.  I have other nickpicks but frankly this is a feature that has no equivalence on Android currently.

[image]

Comment: Related/dupe? [Profile Page for Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191301/profile-page-for-android-app?rq=1). Otherwise, could you provide screenshot of "per-site My Profile" looks like on iOS app? Btw, there's no one working on SE mobile apps for now... or ever, though...

Comment: @Somewhat There is the side bar profile(entire network profile) in both android and iphone but no local profile as displayed above.

Comment: On Android app, you can tap the ">" icon on each site to view per-site profile. Is that what you want, or do you just want a shortcut button to that part?

Comment: @Somewhat unfortunately you are going to have to post a picture because on my version there is definitely no ">" icon.

Comment: It is unlikely this feature will be implemented as development on the mobile apps virtually came to a halt. Spending a bounty on it is not going to change that I'm afraid.

Comment: @rene I doubt this is anywhere near as difficult as many of the other features but okay.

Comment: Tap the hamburger icon and then tap your profile picture ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Android app has no view per site profile page.

Oh yes it does:

1. Tap the hamburger icon.
2. Tap your gravatar.
3. Tap the `>` icon at the right side of the screen opposite to the site name to see your profile for that site.

Comment: I would like to say this doesn't work on iPhone's which is at least inconsistent.